# How to perform depth first search in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have simple structure:

```
CREATE TABLE room_chart(
room_id INT,
parent_id INT,
);
```

I can perform breadth-first search with this code

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
    SELECT room_id , parent_id FROM room_chart WHERE parent_id is null
    UNION 
    SELECT room_chart.room_id, room_chart.parent_id FROM room_chart, r WHERE room_chart.parent_id = r.room_id
)
SELECT * from room_list where room_id in (SELECT room_id from r);
```

But how can I perform depth-first search to find all the routes in this tree for example? thanks in advance!

Comment: RDBMS store data in tables, not as a native object-graph - so the idea of "performing" a DFS in SQL is meaningless (as the RDBMS is free to iterate through related records any way it wants (be it DFS, BFS, or something else). Do you mean to say you want the results of the query to be in the same order as though it was a DFS rather than in BFS order? But if you want them in DFS order (or BFS order) you still need to define the relative ordering of sibling nodes - which your current `room_chart` table fails to do - so your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong calling it dfs, goal is to output all the paths of this tree

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098759/postgres-nested-records-in-a-recursive-query-in-depth-first-manner/50100392#50100392