# Preorder tree traversal using recursive CTEs in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query, tree-traversal

I need to traverse a node tree in pre order to generate a menu listing and so far I've come up with this recursive CTE:

```
    WITH RECURSIVE nodes AS (
    SELECT '' as spacer,
           1::numeric as level,
           (rank() OVER (PARTITION BY parent_id order by name ASC ))::numeric as node_rank,
           node_tree.*
    FROM node_tree
    where parent_id IS NULL
UNION
    SELECT parent.spacer || '-' as spacer,
           parent.level * 10.0 as level,
           parent.node_rank + (rank()  OVER (PARTITION BY node.parent_id order by node.name ASC )) / (parent.level * 10.0) as node_rank,
           node.*
    FROM node_tree node
             join nodes parent
                  on parent.id = node.parent_id
)
SELECT 
  trim(spacer || ' ' || name) as item_name,
  id,
  parent_id,
  name
FROM nodes
order by node_rank nulls first, name
```

Assuming that I need to keep the self referencing structure of the table, is there any better method?

This is the minimal schema and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE node_tree (
  id uuid primary key,
  parent_id uuid default null,
  name text
  );
  
ALTER TABLE node_tree ADD CONSTRAINT node_parent_check
CHECK (parent_id is NULL OR parent_id <> id);

ALTER TABLE node_tree 
    ADD CONSTRAINT node_parent_fk 
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
    REFERENCES node_tree(id);
    
    
INSERT INTO node_tree (id,parent_id,name) VALUES
('B4352249-3BCC-4110-964B-368AAA2DCE4C', null, 'Node 1'),
('AE3C21B1-9F4E-4C62-A2C7-2C729591CE60', 'B4352249-3BCC-4110-964B-368AAA2DCE4C', 'Node 1.1'),
('CED81F20-6598-42EA-95F8-2D5E8B1FCA73', 'AE3C21B1-9F4E-4C62-A2C7-2C729591CE60', 'Node 1.1.1'),
('9B2BC4D7-D387-4726-A3E2-2466883152CC', 'AE3C21B1-9F4E-4C62-A2C7-2C729591CE60', 'Node 1.1.2'),
('1492A9D9-D24F-47E6-9926-9D198B7F57A0', 'B4352249-3BCC-4110-964B-368AAA2DCE4C', 'Node 1.2'),
('F1B22F5B-34A7-4A92-9792-C2D023147E4D', '1492A9D9-D24F-47E6-9926-9D198B7F57A0', 'Node 1.2.1'),
('5B0AA9B2-1DB8-4DDE-A184-77872F2BC990', '1492A9D9-D24F-47E6-9926-9D198B7F57A0', 'Node 1.2.2'),
('7450E2EC-3E20-45F0-BE59-9F5BEE7D2955', null, 'Node 2'),
('F60B7772-D6E3-42A7-8AAE-D6CB862F4D96', '7450E2EC-3E20-45F0-BE59-9F5BEE7D2955', 'Node 2.1'),
('954C6010-DA37-41B1-8933-93B15552E6CB', 'F60B7772-D6E3-42A7-8AAE-D6CB862F4D96', 'Node 2.1.1'),
('2F3EBEC7-B038-4E7D-B7AF-F22D524B1AF8', '954C6010-DA37-41B1-8933-93B15552E6CB', 'Node 2.1.1.1'),
('4BA13434-2DA5-4913-B9F6-5AFEF4892000', '954C6010-DA37-41B1-8933-93B15552E6CB', 'Node 2.1.1.2'),
('337238CC-FED0-40D2-B54B-603A36C075A0', 'F60B7772-D6E3-42A7-8AAE-D6CB862F4D96', 'Node 2.1.2'),
('F7996999-D024-428A-BF61-78958695DDB3', null, 'Node 3'),
('81BAE0B8-70CF-4152-BCBF-632964E30904', 'F7996999-D024-428A-BF61-78958695DDB3', 'Node 3.1'),
('E88F9BD9-4288-46FC-9972-215623BE3949', '81BAE0B8-70CF-4152-BCBF-632964E30904', 'Node 3.1.1'),
('992AE037-9DAA-49D9-A725-AC1BBCE46037', null, 'Node 4'),
('9CFC7634-E1DA-4AC3-9D9D-4995B28EB148', '992AE037-9DAA-49D9-A725-AC1BBCE46037', 'Node 4.1'),
('E53C022B-1E4E-4D6F-A740-26A23211BF1F', '9CFC7634-E1DA-4AC3-9D9D-4995B28EB148', 'Node 4.1.1');
```

Here is a DB fiddle of it: [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wrH8Cw8xxnLCkpMrhtCcp8/2)

Comment: Is the tree always a binary tree? Should we consider that the lowest id is on the left and the highest on the right?

Comment: Your third column could be used (somewhat adjusted) to use the ltree extension: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html This is a plugin which can handle tree structures stored like "1.2.3" very well. So, you don't need to created huge recursive CTEs, further reading: http://patshaughnessy.net/2017/12/13/saving-a-tree-in-postgres-using-ltree

Comment: @FabianPijcke The tree is not a binary one, each node can have an indefinite number of descendants.

Comment: @S-Man The name in the third column is just an example to help myself compose a sample tree.

In reality, the names of the nodes are descriptive names used in an UI element and cannot be constrained to a specific format.

Answer (score 1):

**Path enumeration with [arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/arrays.html)**

This will use up a lot of "unnecessary" memory for deeply nested trees, but it is the best I can come up with and should work in some use cases at least.

Table:

```
psql <<'EOF'
DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS "tmp";
CREATE TABLE "tmp" (
  "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  "parentId" INTEGER,
  "childIndex" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "value" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY ("parentId") REFERENCES "tmp"("id")
);
EOF
```

Data:

```
psql <<'EOF'
INSERT INTO "tmp" VALUES
(3, NULL, 0, 1, 'one'  ),
(1, 3,    0, 2, 'two'  ),
(2, 3,    1, 3, 'three'),
(0, 1,    0, 4, 'four' ),
(4, 1,    1, 5, 'five' )
EOF
```

Represented tree:

```
     1
    / \
   2   3
  / \
 4   5
```

Query:

```
psql <<'EOF'
WITH RECURSIVE "cte" (
  "id",
  "parentId",
  "childIndex",
  "value",
  "name",
  "prefix"
) AS (
  SELECT
    "id",
    "parentId",
    "childIndex",
    "value",
    "name",
    array[0]
  FROM "tmp"
  WHERE "parentId" IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    "child"."id",
    "child"."parentId",
    "child"."childIndex",
    "child"."value",
    "child"."name",
    "parent"."prefix" || "child"."childIndex"
  FROM "tmp" AS "child"
  JOIN "cte" AS "parent"
    ON "child"."parentId" = "parent"."id"
)
SELECT * FROM "cte"
ORDER BY "prefix"
EOF
```

Output in the desired preorder:

```
 id | parentId | childIndex | value | name  | prefix  
----+----------+------------+-------+-------+---------
  3 |          |          0 |     1 | one   | {0}
  1 |        3 |          0 |     2 | two   | {0,0}
  0 |        1 |          0 |     4 | four  | {0,0,0}
  4 |        1 |          1 |     5 | five  | {0,0,1}
  2 |        3 |          1 |     3 | three | {0,1}
```

`SEARCH` is a shortcut keyword that produces the exact same query with less verbose code:

```
psql <<'EOF'
WITH RECURSIVE "cte" (
  "id",
  "parentId",
  "childIndex",
  "value",
  "name"
) AS (
  SELECT
    "id",
    "parentId",
    "childIndex",
    "value",
    "name"
  FROM "tmp"
  WHERE "parentId" IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    "child"."id",
    "child"."parentId",
    "child"."childIndex",
    "child"."value",
    "child"."name"
  FROM "tmp" AS "child"
  JOIN "cte" AS "parent"
    ON "child"."parentId" = "parent"."id"
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY "childIndex" SET "prefix"
SELECT * FROM "cte"
ORDER BY "prefix"
EOF
```

The trick is to create a `prefix` array column that registers the full path to each element, and then order by that, which happens in lexicographical order.

This and some other related techniques are also documented in the manual at: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE

Tested on Postgresql 15.4, Ubuntu 23.04.

Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63153/how-do-i-sort-the-results-of-a-recursive-query-in-an-expanded-tree-like-fashion