# Depth-first pre-order traversal of a tree

Tags: sql, postgresql, tree

Look at this closure table:

| ancestor | descendant | path_length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 6 | 0 |
| 4 | 6 | 1 |
| 2 | 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 7 | 0 |
| 4 | 7 | 1 |
| 2 | 7 | 2 |
| 8 | 8 | 0 |
| 6 | 8 | 1 |
| 4 | 8 | 2 |
| 2 | 8 | 3 |

[image]

Now I want this in order:

```
1
2
4
6
8
7
5
3
```

Notice that all of a node's ancestors may not have a lower node number. Is it possible with a SQL query?

**My attempt:** Using [PostgreSQL documentation section 7.8.2.1. Search Order](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), I found the following solution:

```
WITH RECURSIVE search_tree(descendant, path) AS (
SELECT descendant, ARRAY[ROW(ct.ancestor, ct.descendant)]
FROM closure_table ct WHERE descendant = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT
ct.descendant, path || ROW(ct.ancestor, ct.descendant)
FROM closure_table ct, search_tree st
WHERE ct.ancestor = st.descendant AND ct.path_length = 1
)
SELECT * FROM search_tree ORDER BY path;
```

which you can see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/eb5e0f/1/0). But I don't know how efficient it is.

Comment: Is it a table formatting problem or your table has 9 fields, which are 3 same fields repeated 3 times (at schema level)?

Comment: It is just one table with three columns and 17 rows.

Comment: Check the correctness of the updated table and consider adding information regarding the DBMS you're currently using and attempted queries if any.

Comment: @lemon Actually your solution was correct. Please re-post your answer again. Just needed not to be in descending order.

Comment: Related without the closure table using recursive queries instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65247873/preorder-tree-traversal-using-recursive-ctes-in-sql

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**: Finding the roots of your tree

Given your input table, you can do this by selecting

- all ancestors with "*path_length = 0*" (to select them only once)
- that are not found among the descendants with "*path_length > 0*" (those nodes that are found at least from level = 1 going on).

```
SELECT ancestor AS root FROM tab WHERE path_length = 0
EXCEPT
SELECT descendant FROM tab WHERE path_length > 0
```

| root |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

---

**Step 2**: Implementing the Depth-First Search for you binary tree.

This can be done by

- scanning rows whose "*ancestor*" value only belongs to the roots table (to avoid duplicate "*descendant*" values) by joining previous table
- applying the depth-first ordering.

Depth-first ordering will order based on:

- ancestors first
- the first son of each child in a recursive (depth-first) way, using a ranking value from the `ROW_NUMBER` window function,
- the path_length ascendently when it's going deep towards the leaves, the same path_length descendently when it's going upper towards the roots, using a `CASE` construct to handle the two situations.

```
WITH roots AS (
    SELECT ancestor AS root FROM tab WHERE path_length = 0
    EXCEPT
    SELECT descendant FROM tab WHERE path_length > 0
), ranked_nodes AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ancestor, path_length
                                ORDER     BY descendant           ) AS rn
    FROM tab
    INNER JOIN roots
            ON tab.ancestor = roots.root
)
SELECT descendant
FROM ranked_nodes
ORDER BY ancestor, 
         rn, 
         CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN path_length ELSE -path_length END
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wgvAbcZmHuw82kGJjNnGpq/2).

---

The upper one is a generalized solution, though if you assume knowing in advance the values of your roots (1, 2 and 3), you can simplify the query as follows:

```
WITH ranked_nodes AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ancestor, path_length
                                ORDER     BY descendant           ) AS rn
    FROM tab
    WHERE ancestor <= 3
)
SELECT descendant
FROM ranked_nodes
ORDER BY ancestor, 
         rn, 
         CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN path_length ELSE -path_length END
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But your query returns `1, 8, 6, 4, 2, 7, 5, 3` while I am looking for `1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 7, 5, 3`.

Comment: This is not DFS, last thing I changed was adding last `DESC` on descendant, though this breaks the order on the last values.

Comment: Try with the updated answer. @Dante

Comment: It works. Thanks. I should learn about  [window functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function_(SQL)), right?

Comment: Definitely. They're one of the most efficient tools in sql querying. I'd recommend you to follow this link, as it brings full detailed descriptions seasoned with handy examples >> https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/. For the official documentation instead you can check here >> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html.

Comment: I wish I could do more upvotes :-)

Comment: I just found out that it works only if the tree nodes' numbers are in order beforehand. For example if I change 2 to 22, it does not work anymore.

Comment: That's correct. In this post's specific case, placeholder and ordering values are identical, while in this case you're mentioning placeholder and ordering values would be different. If you don't have that kind of ordering, you have to generate it beforehand (apart from their placeholder value) with further subqueries (at least one more I'd say).