# SQL to retrieve entire path from a parent child table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm oversimplifying my problem a bit.

I have a table with the following format:

| id | parent_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [null] | id1 |
| 2 | 1 | id2 |
| 3 | 2 | aa3 |
| 4 | 3 | bb4 |
| 5 | 2 | abc |
| 6 | [null] | abc1 |

I want to retrieve, in SQL ideally the path to root - (ie. node with parent_id = null)
For example:

```
getPath(5) -> "id1 / id2 / abc"
getPath(4) -> "id1 / id2 / aa3 / bb4" 
getPath(6) -> "abc1"
```

I've already build a python function that constructs the path - while loop breaking when parent_id is null and inserting the name at the beginning of the string, but I'm hoping there's a way of getting this solved with a single DB operation, as opposed to multiple selects.

Any pointers on where to find a solution?

Many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres: Nested records in a Recursive query in depth first manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098759/postgres-nested-records-in-a-recursive-query-in-depth-first-manner)

Comment: Retracted close vote because this is now a better answer than that was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to do you can no doubt improve this. Perhaps you want the path as an array for example.

Note that something very similar will work in most modern databases from sqlite3 to IBM db2 - consult your local documentation.

Something like:

```sql
;
CREATE TABLE nodes (
  "id" int primary key,
  parent_id int,
  name text,
  -- other fields go here
  unique(parent_id, id) -- creates an index
 );
 
 
 CREATE VIEW hierarchy_view AS
 WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy AS (
  -- Handle case where no parent.
  SELECT 
    id, parent_id, id root_id, name, 
    name path,
    ARRAY[id]::int[] id_path,
    0::int depth
  FROM nodes t
  WHERE parent_id is null
  UNION ALL
  -- Handle case where there is a parent.
  -- In this case the "path" is the parent_path and name, 
  -- concatenated with ' / ' as a separator.
  SELECT 
    child.id, child.parent_id, parent.root_id, child.name, 
    parent.path || (' / ' || child.name) path,
    parent.id_path || child.id id_path,
    parent.depth + 1 depth
  FROM nodes child
  INNER JOIN hierarchy parent
    ON parent.id = child.parent_id
)
SELECT * 
FROM hierarchy h;
```

Now let's populate some values:

```sql
 insert into nodes(id, parent_id, name) 
 values
 (1, null, 'foo'),
 (2, 1, 'bar'),
 (3, 1, 'baz'),
 (4, 2, 'quux'),
 (5, 4, 'ftang')
 ;
```

To query:

```sql
-- Get path for a node
SELECT path FROM hierarchy_view WHERE id = :id

-- Get whole tree for a node, sorted by path
SELECT * FROM hierarchy_view WHERE parent_id = :parentId
ORDER BY path ASC, id_path ASC
```

You will want indexes on `id` and `parent_id` at the very least.

Comment: DB Fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aHAi9uDwXivUvw4rin33uV/0

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a `recursive` query with `concat`, by simply pass the `id` in the extern where clause to get the path

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte(id, path) AS (
  SELECT id, t.name
  FROM mytable t
  WHERE parent_id is null
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.id, concat(path,'/', t.name)
  FROM mytable t
  INNER JOIN cte c ON c.id = t.parent_id
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE id = 5;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/TKQiOwxI)

Answer (score 0):

The query below is comprised of a function containing a recursive `cte` to generate the path. The function can then be called per your example to produce the path elsewhere in your script:

```
create or replace function getPath(node_id int) returns text as $$
   with recursive cte(id, p_id, v) as (
      select t.* from tbl t where t.parent_id is null
      union all
      select t.id, t.parent_id, c.v||'/'||t.name from cte c 
      join tbl t on  t.parent_id = c.id
   )
   select min(c.v) from cte c where c.id = node_id
$$
language sql
```

Usage:

```
select getPath(5) -- id1/id2/abc
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Dy31MVeh)

Answer (score 0):

If you are retrieving the path for each id returned in another result set, it would make more sense to join directly to a recursive CTE which is seeded with the root node of the hierarchy.

When getting/building the path for a specific node it does not make sense to start at the root and build the entire tree. We should be starting with the specified node and walking up the tree:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, parent_id, path) AS (

    SELECT id, parent_id, name
    FROM tbl
    WHERE id = 5 -- the id of the node for which we need to build the path

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, CONCAT_WS(' / ', t.name, path)
    FROM tbl t
    JOIN cte c ON t.id = c.parent_id

)
SELECT path
FROM cte
WHERE parent_id IS NULL;
```

Or wrapped in a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getPath(node_id INT) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
    WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, parent_id, path) AS (
        SELECT id, parent_id, name
        FROM tbl
        WHERE id = node_id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, CONCAT_WS(' / ', t.name, path)
        FROM tbl t
        JOIN cte c ON t.id = c.parent_id
    )
    SELECT path FROM cte WHERE parent_id IS NULL
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
```

Usage:

```
SELECT getPath(5); -- returns "id1 / id2 / abc"
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GwCjCUdH)